# About the orthogonality catastrophe

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics

I am reading the book of Mahan. In the section of orthogonality catastrophe, I can understand that the two N-particle Slater determinants ($\Phi_i$ and $\Phi_f$) are almost orthogonal as $N\rightarrow \infty $. This is purely mathematical.

But I cannot see how this overlap
$$  S = \int d^3 r_1 \cdots  d^3 r_n \Phi_f^*(r_1, \cdots, r_n) \Phi_i (r_1,\cdots, r_n)  $$
will be relevant for any physical process.

Even if they appear at the same time in some expression, there should be some physical quantity between them, right?

Here is some excerpt from his book

[image]

Comment: The overlap (or rather its modulus squared) is the [Loschmidt echo](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Loschmidt_echo). It can be directly measured by Ramsey interferometry, using a controllable two-state system (such as a magnetic impurity) as the scatterer. This has been proposed, although not experimentally realised to my knowledge, in the context of ultracold fermionic gases, see for example [Goold et al., Phys. Rev. A 84, 063632 (2011)](http://arxiv.org/abs/1104.2577).

Comment: @MarkMitchison But I do not think this has anything to do with orthogonality catastrophe.

Comment: Did you look at the linked paper? The title begins with "Orthogonality catastrophe..."